# LWC @api param is being passed by reference or not?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

I have a parent component with this JavaScript code:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class ParentComponent extends LightningElement {
  myValue = {
       value:'hello'
  };

  // ... other code for the button and the comparison mentioned below.
}
```

and this html:

```
<template>
    <c-child-component my-property={myValue}></c-child-component>
</template>
```

Then I have the child component with this js:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class ChildComponent extends LightningElement {
     @api myProperty;
}
```

and a non relevant html.

The thing is that if, on button click in the parent component, I run this code:

```
this.template.querySelector("c-child-component").myProperty === this.myValue
```

I'm getting false from that comparison. Is that correct, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are passed by reference, as you'd expect, except there's a security layer that's added, implemented as a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). The exact implementation details differ between environments (Locker Service, Lightning Web Security, Lightning Web Runtime), but the end results are the same for each. `===` will always return false for any objects that cross the boundary layer, and sometimes even within the same component, depending on the scope of the variable and what methods you use on it.

Comment: Phew, okay, well it's good to know that I wasn't crazy and that something else was happening. The real application of the code wasn't running on a click of a button but on a click of a child component that was throwing an event. My idea was to pass the input param in that event to find out what component was clicked.

Comment: Do you know if there is any other way to identify the object that was passed to the component? I mean, without getting into the issue of generating unique keys for each object in the array. Specifically, considering the possibility that two objects could have the same payload.

Comment: The components are being created from an array with a template for:each tag

Comment: @JuandelaFuente (a) `handle(event) { let index = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('c-child-component')].findIndex((el)=>el===event.target) ...` should work. Alternatively, you can change `for:each` to `iterator:it`, which would then give you access to `{it.index}`, which could be on the child: `data-index={it.index}` ... `handle(event) { let index = event.target.dataset.index; ...` In other words, you really do want to have a way to get to the index.